# jQuery custom confirm boxes allowing / blocking cought events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have something like a delete form which should require pressing "Yes- Delete" within modal confirmation box. So basically someting like this

```
$('#my-form').on('submit', function(e) {
  var r = confirm("Really Delete?");

  if (r != true) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

So this is working, but I do not want the ugly browser confirm boxes. I'd like to use my own dialogs.

My Problem is basically that the confirm method stops the script execution, therefore I do not need to call preventDefault if nothing is pressed yet.

Are there any good solutions / best practices for this?

Comment: Use callbacks or promises; it's not possible to pause a script in the middle.

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically catch the thrown event and rerun it after confirmation without opening the dialog again? I want to use this in many forms and therefore need a generic solution

Comment: Since you are using jquery, why dont you try [jquery dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) for this.

Comment: @FrankProvost No, but you can separate it out into different functions which might solve it.

Comment: (By the way you can just do `if (!r) { e.preventDefault() }`

Comment: @gcampbell you might want to provide an example as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [jquery confirm](https://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/) and if user confirm you can call ajax:

```
$('.ajax-form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var self = $(this);
  $(".confirm").confirm({
    text: self.data('confirmation'),
    title: "Confirmation required",
    confirm: function(button) {
        $.ajax({
            method: self.attr('method') || 'GET',
            url: self.attr('action'), 
            data: self.serialize(),
            success: function() {
               // deleted
            }
        });
    }
  });
});
```

and you can have html like this:

```
<form action="/delete" method="POST" data-confirmation="Really Delete?">

</form>
```

Comment: This would require me to write code for every different form i want to use right? i basically would like to build something more generic which works for example for every form attached with the class "ajax-form"

Comment: @FrankProvost see my updated answer, it should work for every form that have class `ajax-form`.